# Why is HONH2 basic?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

I've been told that $\ce{HONH2}$ is a weak base because of its $K_b$ value of $\pu{1.1E-8}$. However, the $K_a$ value is larger ($K_a=K_w/K_b=9.9\times10^{-7}$), which I think would make it more likely to lose rather than gain a proton. What is the error in my understanding?

Comment: The Ka belongs to NH3OH+, not to NH2OH.(frequent mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing the $K_b$ of $\ce{H2NOH}$ with the $K_a$ of its conjugate acid $\ce{H3NOH^+}$. To assess
whether $\ce{H2NOH}$ has a net acidic or basic character in water you have to compare its $K_b$ with the $K_a$ of $\ce{H2NOH}$ itself, not with the $K_a$ of its conjugate acid.

The autodissociation product $K_w$ relates the $K_b$ of a solute with the $K_a$ of the conjugate acid, not with the $K_a$ of the same solute species. We can only suppose, generally, that the proper $K_a$ for comparison is less than the conjugate-acid $K_a$ you get using the ion product.

So how much less? That varies from solute to solute. In the case of $\ce{H2NOH}$ the $K_a$ of the neutral molecule is *a lot* less than that of the conjugate-acid cation, too small even to be evident in aqueous alkali. With the neutral $\ce{H2NOH}$ molecule, as opposed to the cation, $K_b$ wins hands down and thus $\ce{H2NOH}$ will act in water as a weak base.

Comment: Care to produce an alternativecanswer maybe?